# Standard Deviation for Normally Distributed Bell Curve - Worded Problem

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

[image]

My working out:

Z = (14-9.5)/2.25 = 2

% less than 2 = 95%

Answer is 97.5 % .... no idea...

Comment: is it because it's 95 + 2.35 + 0.15 ?

Comment: Are you using the 68/95/99.7 rule?  If so, then 95% is not the amount less than 2, but the amount between -2 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 68/95/99.7 rule, 14 degrees is 2 standard deviations away from the mean.

50% left half + (1/2 of 95% (mean to 2$\sigma$)) and you get 97.5%.